# Azure Functions - Local development with moq unit testing & Continuous Deployment using VSTS Release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am looking for developing Azure Functions as a project in Visual Studio rather than browser based coding that goes to GIT repo and follows Continuous Build and Deployment processes of VSTS existing pipelines. Want to know whether this is possible and also would like to know whether we can build a moq based unit testing for these Function projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mahesh,

You can write your functions using an IDE (Visual Studio, VS Code, Atom, etc.) and setup Continuous Deployment using the same mechanism available to Azure Web Apps (using local Git, GitHub, VSTS, FTP, etc.)
Here is some documentation covering the deployment options:
Git:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/#localgitdeployment
FTP:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/#ftp

You can also see this process, step-by-step, in a //build presentation from one of our PMs, Matthew Henderson, here: https://channel9.msdn.com/events/Build/2016/T692

Although it can be done, currently, the tooling is not at a point where you have a simple development -> testing -> deployment workflow, but that is something we're actively working on.

We provide some information on how to run, debug and test your functions locally here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki

Remote debugging is also available for C# and we'll soon have a CLI in preview.

I hope this information is helpful.